# How to have optional values for an ecto embedded schema?

Tags: elixir, ecto

### Background

I am trying to create an embedded schema that needs to save information about orders.
Sometimes orders have no `customer_id` and that is fine (for the application).

```
defmodule Order do
  use Ecto.Schema

  embedded_schema do
    field(:customer_id, :integer | nil)
    field(:stage, enum: [:bought | :in_shop_cart | :canceled])
    field(:details, :string)
  end
end
```

### Problem

The issue here is that I get a compile error for `customer_id`:

```
(CompileError) misplaced operator |/2

The | operator is typically used between brackets as the cons operator:

    [head | tail]

where head is a single element and the tail is the remaining of a list.
It is also used to update maps and structs, via the %{map | key: value} notation,
and in typespecs, such as @type and @spec, to express the union of two types
```

I understand the issue here is the use of  `:integer | nil`. This is not a list, so the advice I get is not usable.

### Question

How can I represent optional values in my embedded schema ? (specifically `:something | nil`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipe operator `|` is used to separate the head of a list from its tail (as the error mentions) and it gets used in `@spec` definitions when defining allowed inputs/outputs.

Normally, the migrations are where the nullable/not-nullable definition really matters, but with a virtual schema, I think you're fine just specifying the data type (e.g. `:integer`). If there's no value, a `nil` will be used in its place (similar to how a struct's fields have `nil` values unless defaults were defined).  In other words

```
field(:customer_id, :integer)
# is the same as
field(:customer_id, :integer, default: nil)
```

If you wanted to indicate some "non-nullable" field in an Ecto schema, Set the `:default` option appropriate, e.g.

```
field(:details, :string, default: "")
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can't use `|` in schema like this.

As far as the first case is concerned like in `customer_id`, you can use `default` option to set default a default value if the value isn't provided.

In the second case of `stage` You can use `Ecto's Enum` to restrict only specific values to be entered in the db. You can do something like this:

```
field :status, Ecto.Enum, values: [:foo, :bar, :baz]
```

[Here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Enum.html) is some useful documentaion for further reading about Ecto Enum